# Dividing a string in 2 parts and placing each part in a different new string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string (resultString) that contains long html codes. These codes are grouped in 2 main DIVs, window and Popup.

```
resultString = "<div id=\"window\">window content --- long html codes</div><div id=\"PopUp\">Popup content --- long html codes</div>"
```

Now I want to retrieve the html content of window and popup DIVs separately and place them in 2 different strings (stringWindow and stringPopup).

```
stringWindow = "<div id=\"window\">window content --- long html codes</div>";
stringPopup = "<div id=\"PopUp\">Popup content --- long html codes</div>";
```

Is there any simple way to do so in jQuery/javascript? The stringWindow is constructed in an Ajax json webmethod function. Any help is well appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you want all the div (<div ...>...</div>) or just the content?

Comment: Just the content....

Comment: BTW... Why [tag:c#] and [tag:asp.net]? You are asking a purely JS/jQuery question

Comment: Sorry for the C# tag..... the string is constructed in code behind with C#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `outerHTML`

1. Using **[`filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)** you can filter element with certain selector
2. Now you can use **[`outerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML)** for getting html content

```js
var resultString = "<div id=\"window\">window content --- long html codes</div><div id=\"PopUp\">Popup content --- long html codes</div>",
  stringWindow, stringPopup;

stringWindow = $(resultString).filter('#window')[0].outerHTML;
stringPopup = $(resultString).filter('#PopUp')[0].outerHTML;

console.log(stringPopup, stringPopup);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Trivial in jQuery:

```js
var resultString = "<div id=\"window\">window content --- long html codes</div><div id=\"PopUp\">Popup content --- long html codes</div>"

var $doc = $("<div>" + resultString + "</div>");
var stringWindow = $doc.find('#window').text();
var stringPopup = $doc.find('#PopUp').text();
console.log("window", stringWindow);
console.log("popup", stringPopup);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- results pane console output; see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242491 -->
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Not much harder in plain JS.

If by "Just the content" you don't mean "text" but markup inside the div, then replace `text()` with `html()`.

EDIT: made into executable snippet.

Comment: You're accesing DOM object, not working with strings.

Comment: @Sapikelio: I am constructing DOM object from the string, then manipulating it. No-one should ever parse HTML/XML with anything except a HTML/XML parser. Fortunately, browsers already have one.

Answer (score 2):

A version that doesn't use jQuery, doesn't assume it is in the document or can be put into the document but still interprets it as HTML -

```
var domParser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = domParser.parseFromString(resultString, "text/html"),
    content = ["window", "PopUp"].map(function(id) {
        return doc.querySelector("#" + id).innerHTML;
    }),
    stringWindow = content[0],
    stringPopup = content[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. It works for me. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9agr3d80/1/)

```
resultString = "<div id=\"window\">window content --- long html codes</div>   <div id=\"PopUp\">Popup content --- long html codes</div>";

var res = resultString.split("</div>");

stringWindow = res[0].replace(/^<div[^>]*>|<\/div>$/g, '');
stringPopup = res[1].replace(/^<div[^>]*>|<\/div>$/g, '');
```

Hope It Helps.

Comment: This works for this specific example. It will fail if "long html codes" include `<div>` elements.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may help you :-

```
 var resultString = "<div id=\"window\">window content --- long html codes</div><div id=\"PopUp\">Popup content --- long html codes</div>"
        var splitter = document.createElement('div');
        splitter.innerHTML = resultString;

        var window = $(splitter).find("#window")
        var poppup = $(splitter).find("#PopUp")
```

Mark as an answer if it helps

Comment: This is the idea of my "not much harder in plain JS"; but you have several bugs. You meant `parts[1]` for the `poppup` (sic); and you really did not want to try to redefine the `window` variable, right?

Comment: I want to retrieve the html codes as they are and then I will use those 2 new strings to contrust my aspx page....

Comment: i have updated my answer please check now.....Now you can find the html codes as well as the element context

Answer (score 1):

This is one way  to do it with C#...

It may help...

Given your result string as...

```
resultString = "<div id=\"window\">window content --- long html codes</div><div id=\"PopUp\">Popup content --- long html codes</div>"
```

following should work..

```
string resultPopUp = resultString.Substring(resultString.IndexOf("<div id=\"PopUp"));
string resultWindow = resultString.Substring(resultString.IndexOf("<div id=\"window"), resultString.Length - resultString.IndexOf("<div id=\"PopUp\">")+2);
```

Maintaining the string structure as `<div id=\"*****\">` this should work....

Answer (score 0):

if you want just the content do somthing like this:
with jQuery:

```
 stringWindow =$('#window').innerHTML
 stringPopup =$('#PopUp').innerHTML
```

Only JS:

```
stringWindow =document.getElementById('window').innerHTML
stringPopup =document.getElementById('Popup').innerHTML
```

Comment: As `#window` and `#PopUp` are not found in the document, but in a string variable, this will not work.

Comment: @Amadan why not in the document?

Comment: Because literally the first four words of the question are "I have a string". It does not say "I have a document with these elements".